# Extracting a line from a textfile PHP

Tags: php, text

I Have a text file and want to parse it with PHP

any one has any idea how can I get IMPATTO LTD

```
IMPATTO LTD                               ZAHLUNG:       A
```

from the line above ?

I was thinking maybe regex but there is no uniform way of extracting it.. I guess the best is an expression that will get me the text until the Z from Zahlung.. Is this possible ?

By the way the first words can be of variable length...

Comment: What's the actual criteria for splitting? I'm guessing you don't always have "IMPATTO LTD" or there would be no point extracting it in the first place. Is your terminator always the second `space` character or always some amount of whitespace followed by "ZAHLUNG", or something else?

Comment: take a look at my answer, it might suit you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = null;
$itms = explode('ZAHLUNG', $line);
if(is_array($itms) AND isset($itms[0])) {
    $string = trim($itms[0]);
}

echo $string; // IMPATTO LTD
```

Comment: Congratulation @unset for realising this wasn't a difficult task.

Answer (score 1):

try this one, it reads the file into an array and then loops througth the array line by line to see if your text is found

```
$lines = file('test.txt');
$string_to_find = 'IMPATTO LTD';
foreach ($lines as $line) {
        if(strstr($line,$string_to_find)){
        echo 'found'. $string_to_find;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ZAHLUNG:` is a fixed separator:

```
<?php

$string = 'IMPATTO LTD                               ZAHLUNG:       A';

if( preg_match('/^(.+)ZAHLUNG:/', $string, $matches) ){
    var_dump( trim($matches[1]) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pos = strpos($line, 'ZAHLUNG');
$string = trim(substr_replace($line, '', $pos));
```

if 'ZAHLUNG' is constant then it's a bad idea to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is your friend for this.

```
$pattern = "/IMPATTO LTD/";

$matched = preg_match($pattern, $string);
```

Read up on the man page as this function is *very* powerful and has several useful parameters I did not use in the simple example I posted.

**UPDATE:**

Pardon my bad english it seems I completely misunderstood the question, will delete this post if it does not address proper issue.

Comment: I cannot search for Impatto as this can change any moment as specified but thanks for the thought

Comment: Yeah I reread other answers and realised I was offbase on this! ;) Sorry my friend.